# Why is my Samsung F3 not being recognized via Blacx?

Tags: hard-drive

I just got my hard drive and using my Thermaltake Blacx enclosure, my computer is not detecting it for some reason. I see it in the device manager as "USB Mass Storage", but I don't see anything in my computer. What should i do?

Edit: Could it be jumpers?
Edit: This is a HD103SJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to partition the drive! Just go to disk management and partition the drive and you're good.